# Construct JSON using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am constructing a JSON Body for the POST method for my Odata endpoint call like below

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject sample;
sample = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();

sample["status"] = "New";
sample[ "PROJECT@odata.bind"] = "["+"/PROJECT('" + prjBarcode + "')"+"]";
```

Where PROJECT@odata.bind is an array. I am looking that the JSON to be built like

```
 "status": "New",
 "PROJECT@odata.bind":["/PROJECT('PJ1')"]
```

But with my code above it is generating like

```
  "PROJECT@odata.bind":"[/PROJECT('PJ1')]"
```

Where the `[]` comes with in the `""` how can I fix this

Comment: What's the type of `sample` and how is json generated?

Comment: What is `sample`?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry I updated my question now

Comment: @DavidG I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON, square braces (`[...]`) denote an array, so you need to create one, for example:

```
var array = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray(new string[] {"/PROJECT('" + prjBarcode + "')" });
sample["PROJECT@odata.bind"] = array;
```

You should also consider using [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), it makes your code a lot more readable:

```
var array = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray(new string[] {"/PROJECT('{prjBarcode}')" });
```

Though, I wouldn't be building up JSON like this in the first place. You should create a concrete type to do it that matches your structure and serialise it. For example:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PROJECT@odata.bind")]
    public string[] Projects { get; set; }
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Data
{ 
    Status = "New", 
    Projects = new string[] {$"/PROJECT('{prjBarcode}')" } 
});
```

Comment: I am getting error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'`

Comment: Fixed, and added a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string value for `PROJECT@odata.bind` key and you just need to pass an array

```
sample[ "PROJECT@odata.bind"] =  new JArray(new []{ "/PROJECT('" + prjBarcode + "')" });
```

or you can use another overload of `JArray` constructor

```
sample[ "PROJECT@odata.bind"] =  new JArray("/PROJECT('" + prjBarcode + "')");
```

Comment: I am getting error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken'